# Magento 2 Advanced Js Bundling

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, jsbundling

Can anyone work on **Advanced JS Bundling**?

We would like to apply this concept to one of our client projects.

Could you please explain about Advanced JavaScript bundling in detailed step by step & is there any tools (or) modules need to be installed for verify?, Is it possible to implement advanced JS Bundling in Magento/2.2 (Enterprise)?*

**Note**: I followed **M2developer Docs** but unable to understand & implement. Could you please guide me & would like to know what are the challenges are going to handle?

Is there any difference between JS bundling and Advanced JS bundling?

Comment: where to place m2. devtools??

Comment: also If production mode is enabled  then bundles folder disappears

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I did R & D on this task and prepared some implementation notes it might help you others if you would like to do, please follow the below steps on

**Advanced JS Bundling**.

**A) Required Tools**

1. node.js >= 8.x
2. npm >= 6.x
3. Magento 2 DevTool
4. Git

**B) DevTool Installation**

1. Clone the repository in your local machine
   Ex: git clone https://github.com/magento/m2-devtools.git
2. Run npm install
3. Run npm start (or)npm run build
4. Navigate to **chrome://extensions**
5. Enable Developer mode
6. Click Load unpacked
7. Select the extension folder in the root of this repository
8. Close & reopen chrome browser

[image]
[image]

**C) Usage of DevTool**

1. Visit any page in the storefront in a browser with this extension installed
2. Open RequireJS >> Bundle Generator
3. Click the Record button
4. Begin navigating to critical pages of your store (Home/Catalog/Product/Cart/Checkout)
5. Click the Record button again when you are finished
6. Follow the installation instructions in the Bundle Generator UI

Please refer below link for the usage of DevTool taken an example from default Magento 2.3.1 here

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ysIjzr8ix1d4Vzi3gnwX4prp6-7_1JmM/view

**D) Setup Instructions**

1. Install the Magento_BundleConfig module: This module is currently not consumable via the composer. Manually install the **Magento_BundleConfig** module from Github. Make sure you've run setup: upgrade and that the module is enabled.

**Refer**: https://github.com/magento/m2-devtools/tree/master/Magento_BundleConfig

2.Set Store to Production Mode: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

3.Backup Static Content Source: For the theme that you are bundling, move each language folder to a folder of the same name, appended with **_source**.

For example, 
if you're bundling Luma in English, move **frontend/Magento/luma/en_US** to **frontend/Magento/luma/en_US_source.**

Just rename **en_US** to **en_US_source**

4. Install the RequireJS Optimizer: You must have **node.js** installed locally/Server. Run **npm install -g requirejs**
5. Save the Generated Bundle Config: Click Copy to Clipboard in the Bundle Generator tab. Save the entire configuration in a file called build.js in the root of your store. (You have seen how to get build.js from the above video reference link)

r.js -o build.js baseUrl="pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US_source/" dir="pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/"

**Example**: 
r.js -o build.js baseUrl="pub/static/frontend/Demo/Learning/en_US_source/" dir="pub/static/frontend/Demo/Learning/en_US/"

If the above steps have been performed correctly, your store should now be running with optimized JavaScript bundles.

https://prnt.sc/no7j3z

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nagaraju Kasa, Is it possible to implement it on Magento 2.2.x? Thanks! Pablo

Comment: yes might be possible, i am working to apply the same concept to one of my project version 2.2.2 EE

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Nagaraju Kasa. I need to implement it on Magento 2.2.2CE.

Comment: @pablo Garcia Please feel free to ask if you have any quires regarding advanced js bundling. Please let me know once u applied this concept to your project (or) default magento. thanks

Comment: Sure! I'll keep you posted about it! Thanks @Nagaraju Kasa. Also let me know if you were able to implement it on 2.2.2EE please.

Comment: Yes. @PabloGarcia we can able to do. Please implement on dev instance.

Comment: @Nagaraju Kasa - Thanks man working fine for M2 EE 2.3.1

Comment: @PMB sounds good congrats.

Comment: @PMB i need your suggestion on how you have installed node & npm version on EE cloud. since we have tried to install those tools using hooks concept from .magento.app.yml file but no luck.

Comment: @Nagaraju Kasa - I am not using cloud

Comment: hi, what was the result after implementing that? i mean how much performance was increased ?

Comment: @AsharRiaz we reached client expectation by using this concept. 30% to 40%  page load speed increased.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa is there any other step to increase performance ? like have you ever removed unused css from magento pages ? Or any other step which boosts magento store performance

Comment: Yes, that steps will help us.

Comment: could you explain steps to remove unused css ?

Comment: I like this made my life easier however don't like the way that compared to my 2.2.x build files I got from here https://github.com/antonkril/magento-rjs-config the shared.js is huge because it includes any file in more than 1 page type where as my old one had a shared that was on all pages. Anyway my pages are about 1mb bigger it seems unless i'm missing something which i could be.

Comment: After implementing this all works except payment method. I am using adyen payment method and it is not showing after implementing above steps. How do we add third party module in build.js manually?  any idea ?

Comment: and also magento recaptcha is not working. When i login from customer login page it works but when i login on checkout page with ajax popup. it says invalid captcha.

Comment: @Nagaraju K, thanks for your useful post. The advanced bundles were all created successfully, one issue however is that all the pages when revisited download all other irrelevant bundles meaning cms/shipping.js bundle also appear on the home page where only default.js should appear? Any idea why this happens and how to remedy it.

Comment: @NagarajuK How to disable this?

Comment: where to place m2. devtools?? 
also If production mode is enabled then bundles folder disappears –

Comment: Does advanced JS bundling have to be repeated each time a new JavaScript dependency from  a newly added module is loading separately?

Comment: as I show in screenshot there is bundler folder generated but after followed all the steps i m not able to see bundler folder .

Comment: I am little bit confusing about these lines:
For example, if you're bundling Luma in English, move frontend/Magento/luma/en_US to frontend/Magento/luma/en_US_source.

Just rename en_US to en_US_source

Please guide me over this steps

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with nodejs v10.23 and npm v6.14. I'm stuck at dev-tools step, i successfully installed in my chrome and i already enabled the chrome developer mode, and npm start is a success also. But the problem is i don't see Magento 2 dev tools on developer/inspection tool

Comment: @TinyDancer I am having same issue, did you solve? I have had this extension working before in the past. Have tried chrome canary, chromium, chrome and developer / production mode on store however the tab still doesn't show extension seems loaded fine!

Comment: @harri not yet, feels like i want to give up on this

Comment: I believe it may be to do with the Magneto 2 detection, edit the m2-devtools-master\extension\devtool.js and force magento detection to true e.g  function isMagento2Store() { return true seems to fire up the tab for me so i can build the bundles.

Comment: hi cnu please help for 2.4.4

Answer (score -9):

If your Magento store is in production mode then

Magento ≥ 2.2   It can be done by the command line

```
 php bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 1
 php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Magento < 2.2

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='1' WHERE `path`='dev/js/enable_js_bundling';
```

Then run this command  php bin/magento cache:clean