# Magento 2 Advanced js bundling - How to resolve console errors?

Tags: javascript

I've followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273914/magento-2-advanced-js-bundling#answer-274946) answer to use advanced js bundling in our Magento 2.4.5-p1. We found some issues after implemented advanced js bundling.

I'm struct at below errors from console. Can anyone please let me know how to fix this issue?

[image: Console error js bundling]

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into the Magento official [devdoc](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/performance-best-practices/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html) on advanced JavaScript bundling.

Please confirm at what step you are getting thi error while setting up Advance JS bundling.

Please check if pub/static/frontend/your-theme has all the bundles created. Also please C=can you please provide the reproducible steps in magento 2 develop with screenshots or details while integrating the Advance JS Bundling?

Thanks